# HTML 5 audio tag: Can't get mp3 file to play on iPad Safari

Tags: ipad, html, audio, safari

I have an HTML5 app that's essentially a soundboard. You click an image and it plays an mp3 file. It works fine on Chrome but not on my iPad Safari. The function looks like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function playSound(theSound) {
    soundDir = "./sounds/";
    filename = soundDir + theSound;
    sound = new Audio(soundDir + theSound);
    sound.setAttribute("autoplay", "autoplay");
    document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].appendChild(sound);
    return true;
}
</script>
```

And it's called like this:

```
onclick=playSound("knife.mp3")
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

More extensive research showed me that 1) Apple doesn't seem to like "autoplay" for bandwidth reasons, and 2) the [jPlayer](http://www.happyworm.com/jquery/jplayer/) people are smarter than I am and have it working already.